# square-root rule of time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, finance

I tried to test the square-root-rule of time for quantiles of a normal distribution.

So i created with the statiscal programming language R two variables

> a<-rnorm(100,mean=2,sd=1)
>
> b<-rnorm(100,mean=2,sd=1)

According to the square-root-rule of time there must be:

> quantile(a+b,0.1)=quantile((a,b),0.1)*sqrt(2)

But this is not the case. Why not?

Comment: The square root of time scaling rule is a statement about distributions of sums of independent normally distributed random variables, which obviously won't be exactly true for a typical sample of size 100. For example, if you take a sample of 100 it's not even true that 95 of them are guaranteed to be below the 0.95 theoretical quantile..

Comment: how can I construct independent normally distributed random variables in R?

Comment: You can't, you can only sample from the distribution. Take a much larger sample in R, say 10,000 and it will probably be approximately true. Also the square root of time scaling rule is only applicable to mean 0 normal random variaables, I didn't notice you set the mean set to 2.

Comment: Why does it only work for mean adjusted data?

Comment: In your example you have two independent normally distributed random variables $X$ and $Y$ with mean 2 and variance 1, so their sum has mean 4 and variance 2, which means that the 0.1 quantile of their sum is $\sqrt{2} z_{0.1} +4$ where $z_{0.1}$ is the 0.1 quantile of the standard normal rv. On the other hand their concatenation has theoretical quantile $z_{0.1} + 2$, see the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's why what you did didn't work. Let $X,Y$ be two independent normally distributed random variables with mean 2 and variance 1 (this is what you sampled from with your R code). This means that $X+Y$ is normally distributed with mean 4 and variance 2, which implies that $$ \frac{X+Y - 4}{\sqrt{2}}$$ is a standard normal random variable, so it follows that $$ P(X+Y \leq \sqrt{2}z_{0.1} + 4) = 0.1 $$ where $z_{0.1}$ is the 0.1 quantile of the standard normal random variable. On the other hand we have $$P(X\leq z_{0.1} + 2) = 0.1 $$ so the quantiles are not scalings of each other by $\sqrt{2}$, because the quantile is linear in the mean but not in the variance.